# Perfered way of locking C# switch case

Tags: c#, asynchronous, locking

```
internal static void ExecuteCommand(NLO nlo)
{
    switch (nlo.action)
    {
        //synchronize each method in case
        case (NLO.Actions.SET):
            swSet(nlo);
            break;
        case (NLO.Actions.ADD):
            swAdd(nlo);
            break;
        default:
            throw new System.Exception("Error");
            //break;
    }
    return;
}
```

i want to lock so each of the methods `swSet` and `swAdd` are able to run in paralell, but lock `swSet` from running in concurrent with itself and same for `swAdd`

Is the easiest way to put locks around each case or to have the lock in the methods themselves or to have `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]`
 on the method?

Will the last solution lock all methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]` is not overly documented, but will generally use the same lock object for all such methods in the same type; [from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.methodimploptions.aspx):

> Only one thread can execute in any of the instance functions, and only one thread can execute in any of a class's static functions.

Frankly I never find that attribute useful. In your case, it sounds like you need separate locking for the two methods:

```
private static readonly object setLock = new object(), addLock = new object();

static void swAdd(...) {
    lock(addLock) {...}
}
static void swSet(...) {
    lock(setLock) {...}
}
```